# Oracle Database: How to check what percentage of a database is over a certain age?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know what percentage of my database is over 2 months old.

What is the best way to do this? I currently am using `SQLDeveloper`.

I am not sure how to do this, as no table in my database has a `"Date"` column?

Comment: add audit columns as inserting_user, updating_user, updated_datetime, inserted_datetime, etc. And after two months you'll be able to do it.

Comment: So there is no of doing this now? Surely there is a way to see when the data was inserted into the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use an [Oracle Flashback [version] Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01004) but you need to have sufficient undo table space to keep the required data for flashback operations.

However, unless you license and configure "Oracle Flashback Data Archive (Oracle Total Recall)" the amount of historical info will be limited.